# Abbreviation expansion with normal command

Tags: vim, vi

Can anyone please explain to me why there is no expansion for abbreviation when it is used with `:normal` command ?

```
:iabbrev mw Microwave
:normal! imw
```

and I get

> ms

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what `normal!` does. From [`:help :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3anormal)

> If the [!] is given, mappings will not be used.

If you use `:normal imw` (without the `!`) it will work as you expect.

In general, you should always use `:normal!` from scripts that are intended to be re-used by other people (i.e. plugins), since you can never be sure which mappings people are using; `:normal imw` may insert the text `imw`, quit vim, make a WHOOOOOOP WHOOP sound, sacrifice your first-born to Justin Bieber, etc.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey I can't get `normal!` to expand abbreviations no matter what I do, only without the `!` (I just tested again to be sure, and it doesn't work for me). I wouldn't expect it to work either, since that's not how `normal!` is supposed to work. So either you have a version of Vim which has a bug (using 8.0.86), or you're mistaken :-)

Comment: +1 for your solution, I withdrew my objection.  Don't know why my version works a little different to yours though, `:normal! i mw` definitely works for me.  I'm on Vim8, maybe there's a change?

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey Hm, strange. I can't get that to work with Vim 8.0.86 no matter what I try.

Comment: Mystery solved, I was actually on Vim 7.4 on this machine.  After updating to Vim 8.0 my results agree with yours.

Comment: @CodieCodeMonkey Curious. Which version of 7.4 were you using *exactly*? I tried 7.4 (w/o patches), 7.4.500, 7.4.1000, 7.4.1500, and 7.4.2000, and it works correct in all those versions.

Comment: Fortunately I captured my version info before upgrading.  Here it is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 30 2016 10:09:26)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-1129
Compiled by MacPorts`